# lookup realtionship in triggers between two objects

Tags: trigger, custom-object, lookup

for example in a lookup relation,customer object is a parent,bike object was child, both have same amount__c field ,when we enter the amount__c  value in customer obj automatically update the amount to Bike object amount__c field

plz help me out

Comment: The simplest approach is to make the relationship a master-detail once and include a [roll-up summary field](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=fields_about_roll_up_summary_fields.htm&language=en_US) on parent called Amount__c that sums the Amount__c field on the bikes. Triggers are harder to get right.

Comment: This is at least the 3rd question I've seen you post asking how to solve something using triggers. All can be solved without code. Take some time to go through the Force.com workbook to learn about built in features of the platform: https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Force.com_workbook

Comment: If you are only updating the amount on the parent and what the child to have the parent value, you can add a cross object formula on the child object to get the parent amount.

Answer (score 1):

As per Keith's comment - try and make it a master-detail.

If you have to do it - try using something like [this open source tool](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries) to help you if you are uncomfortable coding.